# Results given by stored procedure aren't editable

Tags: select, phpmyadmin, edit, procedure

I would love to have a stored procedure which returns a selection which is editable in phpadmin. For example, something as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM students
```

written from the console will allow you to edit the records as far as each row is unique (table with a primary key). However, that same statement within a procedure won't allow it!

The point is that I have a selection that I will be using quite often and it's a bit more complex than the one above. If I copy it and paste it on the console, it's fine, but not so when run from a procedure!

I would appreciate any ideas to work around this limitation.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who read my question. I just figured out that a very simple way to solve this issue is to create a table with my output selection. Then, from the console, I can select and edit whatever I need from that temporary table.

Thanks for your time!